# Typescript generics: why I need to repeat the generic type in my custom type definition?

Tags: typescript

The [axios library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) defines the `get` function as follows:

```ts
get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T>, D = any>(url: string, config?: AxiosRequestConfig<D>): Promise<R>;

interface AxiosResponse<T = any, D = any>  {
  data: T;
  status: number;
  statusText: string;
  headers: AxiosResponseHeaders;
  config: AxiosRequestConfig<D>;
  request?: any;
}
```

I've defined my custom `PaginatedApiReponse` for paginated results, because many of my responses are paginated:

```ts
type PaginatedApiReponse<T = any, D = any> = AxiosResponse<T, D> & {
  headers: AxiosResponseHeaders & {
    'pagination-count': number,
    'pagination-limit': number,
    'pagination-page': number,
  };
}
```

And I want to use it to get a nice auto-complete and type check:

```ts
axios.get<Product[], PaginatedApiReponse>('/api/producs'):
```

However `res.data` isn't correctly typed to `Product[]`. On the contrary, the `headers` defined in `PaginatedApiResponse` works. The only way I make this work is to type also the second parameter, that is:

```
axios.get<Product[], PaginatedApiReponse<Product[]>>('/api/producs'):
```

Most important thing is this is not needed when using the original `AxiosReponse`. Why I need to repeat the `T` with my custom type?

Answer (score 0):

I was looking into the definition of `get` and axios library. What I see is that get has default parameters as (fully expanded):

```js
get<T = any, R = AxiosResponse<T, any>, D = any>
```

Now consider these types:

```js
// first example
get<Product[]>
// equivalent to:
get<Product[], AxiosResponse<Product[], any>, any>

// second example
get<Product[], AxiosResponse<String>>
// equivalent to
get<Product[], AxiosResponse<String, any>, any>

// third example
get<Product[], String>
// equivalent to
get<Product[], String, any>
```

Basically you can put WHATEVER datatype as second parameter in `get` since there is no constraint but the default it takes will be `AxiosResponse<T,any>` where `T` will be taken from the first parameter.

Now if you call it with the following signature:

```js
get<Product[], PaginatedApiReponse>
// same as this
get<Product[], PaginatedApiReponse<any, any>, any>
// as per your definition, translates to
get<Product[], AxiosResponse<any, any>, any>
```

But what you need is `get<Product[], AxiosResponse<Product[], any>, any>` 
So you need to specifically put `PaginatedApiReponse<Product[]>` in order to translate it to `AxiosResponse<Product[], any>`